# Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown- block(179,6) error setting up Simulink (Matlab)

Tags: sd-card, simulink

I've just installed the Simulink support for my Raspberry Pi: https://se.mathworks.com/hardware-support/raspberry-pi-simulink.html

But when I try to boot the pi I get the error: `Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown- block(179,6)`

The error was originally: `Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown- block(179,2)`, but I found somewhere I should change the `2` in a file to a `6` to solve the issue, but it didn't.

That's why I'm here now, as I fail to find any actual solutions. Is there another way to fix this issue? Is there another way to set my pi up with Simulink, or is the current package just corrupt?

- I'm using the Raspberry Pi 3 B
- I've tried with multiple SD cards
- I am certain the board gets enough power